# What are the similarities between {c++} Vertex* myList and {java} List myList?

Tags: java, c++, pointers

This question may be a little bit self-explanatory for some of you but I am really trying to understand what are the similarities between: `List myList = new ArrayList<Vertex>();` { In JAVA } and `Vertex* myList = new Vertex[size]` {In C++}. What's the point of that `*` in C++ that does not exist in Java. I know that it points to the first element of the list..when are we supposed to use `*`? Is it just for vectors or?

Comment: `Vertex* myList = new Vertex[size]` has been replaced by `std::vector<Vertex> myList(size)`.  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Vertex* myList means that myList is a pointer to a Vertex (because standart C arrays are stored as a pointer to the first element). https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointers.htm

Comment: It is a mistake to think that Java `ArrayList` is like an array. They are two very different things.

Comment: @AndyTurner I wouldn't say they're so different that comparisons can't be made, but this is definitely a bad example. Still, I think this question is more "What is a pointer?" than a question about arrays.

Comment: There is an interesting thing in the description of go's type syntax which explains about `*`: although we tend to write `Vertex* myList`, the original intent was to write `Vertex *myList`, to mean that "the type of `*myList` is `Vertex`". Since `*` dereferences a pointer type to its type, this means that `myList` is a pointer to a `Vertex`. It's a bit roundabout, but that is, apparently, where the notation arose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot talk about similarities/differences when these two languages have different assumptions.

In Java everything is a reference - you are creating objects, they are being stored somewhere (on stack/heap) but you are accessing them only by reference. That means that in `myList` there will be address kept for the `ArrayList` instance (real instance - in memory)

In C++ you can access object as objects (with all after-effects like copying whole object when passing as argument to function) but also by reference (using pointers - just to avoid such after-effects but also to use some special gifts given to pointers like iterating over memory cells).

Yeah - about iterating over computer memory - the funny fact in C++ is that it's allocating **solid block of memory** (I mean - next N cells/addresses in row) to put array there - that's why you can declare your array as

```
int* a = new int[100]; // this is called dynamic allocation
```

because what you need is the address of the first element, and the object size (given by pointer type). You can jump to the next element simply by doing

```
a++
```

To differ using object/pointer you need (or do not need) asterix operator `*` and that's why it occurs in C++.

read also [What exactly is the purpose of the (asterisk) in pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962658/what-exactly-is-the-purpose-of-the-asterisk-in-pointers)

Comment: Oh alright. But which one is better in C++ then, access by reference or by object?

Comment: actually when it comes to arrays you can only access them as pointers - even when you are declaring array as array (I mean `int a[100]`) it still will be sent to functions and kept under `a` variable as pointer the the first element - that limitation is because of performance (try to imagine copying 1mln elements on function call). Of course dereffered array element like `a[100]` or `a++` is an object unless you are keeping another pointers in array - why not

Comment: Oh so basically whenever I declare an array `int a[100]` c++ has to copy that for me into a pointer variable `int* a` which is means extra work?

Comment: it does not mean extra work - I'm pretty sure that it's being changed during compilation

Comment: I never checked that but really I don't think so